# common or browser module on lazyload angular

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I'm using lazy load, but when opening the child component i'm getting this error

```
core.js:10144 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I have read many articles, there had said that I'll add `Common Module` or `Browser Module` I have added these modules in the `app module` but there was no a difference also I have tried to add the modules into `system.module` but unfortunately there was no difference, where I should add these modules?

**App module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SystemModule } from './view/system/system.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SystemModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**System Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SystemRoutingModule } from './system-routing.module';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { SystemComponent } from './system.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './components/chat/chat.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SystemComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ChatComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    SystemRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [
      HomeComponent,
      ChatComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class SystemModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CommonModule needs to be imported into the module where your component is declared.

That means when lazy loading your module, you need to import them.

Adding it to your SystemModule should resolve the issue. If not, please provide a reproductible example showing the issue (you can use Stackblitz to do that).